# Break statement inside a cuda kernel for loop is giving issues

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm playing with cuda/numba codes recently. I have a MxN matrix (say, cumul_A) where each row is a cumulative probability distribution. I want to draw a sample from these cumulative distributions by mapping a sample from a uniform random distribution. In simpler terms, lets say the sample drawn from an uniform random distribution is 0.3. The cuda kernel should pick a row of 'cumul_A' and compare each element of the row (starting with the first element of the row) with 0.3. Once it gets a value greater than 0.3, the kernel should store the index of the element in the output argument and break the for loop. I could not get this seemingly simple kernel to work. Is the break statement causing any trouble inside the kernel?
The minimum working example is provided below.

```
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function

    import numpy as np

    from numba import vectorize, cuda, jit
    np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)

    # Number of rows
    M = 10
    # Number of columns
    N = 20

    # ======= 1-D GRIDS =======
    # Set the number of threads in a block
    threadsperblock_1d = 4
    # Calculate the number of thread blocks in the grid
    blockspergrid_1d = np.int(np.ceil(M / threadsperblock_1d))
    # ======= 1-D GRIDS =======

    @cuda.jit('void(float32[:, :], float32[:], int32[:])')
    def get_randomchoice(cumul_a, random_nos, output):
      x = cuda.grid(1) 
      if x < cumul_a.shape[0]:
        for y in range(cumul_a.shape[1]):
          if random_nos[x] > cumul_a[x, y]:
            output[x] = y
            break # return

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      # Prepare the matrix whise each row is a cumulative probability distribution
      A = np.random.rand(M, N).astype(np.float32)
      A = np.divide(A,np.sum(A,axis=1,keepdims=True))
      cumul_A = np.cumsum(A, axis=1)

      # Put an assertion that cumul_A is indeed cumulative
      assert np.allclose(cumul_A[:,-1],np.ones(M))

      # Draw values from uniform distribution
      RandValues = np.random.rand(M).astype(np.float32)

      # Output array in numpy
      Y = np.zeros(M, dtype=np.int32)
      for iStep in range(M):
        Y[iStep] = np.argwhere(RandValues[iStep] <= cumul_A[iStep])[0]

      print('From numpy:\n{}'.format(Y))

      # Transfer to GPU
      cumul_A_gpu = cuda.to_device(cumul_A)
      RandValues_gpu = cuda.to_device(RandValues)
      # Return array from GPU
      random_idx_gpu = cuda.device_array(M, dtype=np.int32)
      get_randomchoice[blockspergrid_1d, threadsperblock_1d](cumul_A_gpu, RandValues_gpu, random_idx_gpu)
      random_idx = random_idx_gpu.copy_to_host()

      print('From cuda:\n{}'.format(random_idx))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Its a false alarm! There's a glitch in the code. Line `if random_nos[x] > cumul_a[x, y]:` will be `if random_nos[x] < cumul_a[x, y]:`. No issues with 'break' inside for loop.